# Set window size for xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, macos, window, xlsxwriter

I cannot set the window size for created excel file with xlsxwriter and it always creates small window on OSX. Is there a way to set window size on xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't an API to do it in XlsxWriter (you could open a feature request if you like).

In the meantime you can change these properties in the workbook object, shown below with the inbuilt defaults:

```
    workbook.window_width = 16095
    workbook.window_height = 9660
```

I'm not sure what the units are but it is probably [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip).

**Update**: I've add a workbook [`set_size`()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#set_size) method for this.

Comment: Well, no need for API then, that's what I was looking for, thanks.